# Why are images not showing in Azure inventory in ManageIQ?

Tags: azure, manageiq

I'm using ManageIQ as our cloud management platform to provision resources in Azure.  I am having strange issues related to images available in ManageIQ for making provisioning requests.  I understand that the list of images comes from Azure as part of the inventory refresh.  But I cannot figure out where in Azure to find these images.  Does anyone know?  Also, why, when I have 2 manageIQ instances running (One for dev, and one for prod), why can both instances view the same VM's currently running but they don't retrieve the same images?  (Prod shows 3 images while dev shows none).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

the available images are set in settings–> server–> Advanced under `market_image_urns` Mine currently reads:

```
  :azure:
    :get_market_images: true
    :get_private_images: true
    :market_image_urns:
    - RedHat:RHEL:7-LVM:latest
    - MicrosoftWindowsServer:WindowsServer:2019-Datacenter:latest
    - RedHat:RHEL:7.3:7.3.2017051117
```